# View PDF document on HTML5 page

Tags: html, pdf

I want render only PDF document via html5page but i want use my custom style with it for only `<div>`, its possible?

Just show a clean white page with pdf, no gray rectangle via object, only with `<div>`

Comment: What about [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) ?

Comment: Its not good, because view is not correctly ...